# Using Field Calculator to create origin and destination lines on map?

Tags: field-calculator

I'm a novice GIS user.

I'm trying to create origin and destination lines on a map. I now I will have to eventually use the points to lines to tool. My question revolves around the attribute table and field calculator. I have to latitudes and longitudes of each location. I need to create a new field to show the transition between the origin and destination points. I am confused about how to go about this and what equation I should put in the field calculator.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GIS SE! Please make sure you take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) so that you are familiar with the model we follow for asking and answering questions. For starters, please include in your question what program you're using, as much detail as possible about the intended results, and what, if anything, you've already attempted to solve this problem on your own. Also, please edit your question title to reflect the content of your question. What does the "transition" between points look like? Just a line?